# How can I type a React.FC with non-optional `children`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When writing TypeScript (tsx) I usually type my React components using `React.FC<Props>` (Or `React.FunctionComponent<Props>`) where `Props` is an interface with my own prop types. The typing system will then add `children?` to the list of props my component takes.

But this makes the `children` props optional.

So we have `React.VFC` for components with no children and `React.FC` for components with optional children. But what can I use for components with mandatory children?

I could do it manually like this, but I was hoping for a cleaner way to do it.

```js
interface ParentFunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithMandatoryChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  displayName?: string;
}

type PropsWithMandatoryChildren<P> = P & { children: ReactNode };
```

Comment: I think you mean `React.VFC` for defining a component w/ no children (as opposed to `React.VFS`). I'm guessing this is a typo, bc there isn't a `VFS` type. I would edit, but the edit queue is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add non-optional `children` to props.

```
import React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Foo: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return <>{props.children}</>;
};

function Bar() {
  return (
    <>
      {/*
        <Foo />     error
        <Foo></Foo> error
      */}

      <Foo>hello</Foo>

      <Foo>
        <div>foo bar</div>
      </Foo>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Now, say you had `React.forwardRef` there too...?
You pass the Props as the second type argument: `React.forwardRef<T, Props>`

Answer (score 2):

I write my function components in that way, if i want mandatory children:

```js
interface IProps {
    title: string;
    children: ReactNode;
}

export const Section = (props: IProps) => {
    const { title, children } = props;

    return (
        ***
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If helper type is not enough, you always can extend react types by writing your own types:

Create types.d.ts file somewhere in the src folder,

Add this code:

```js
declare module React {
    declare interface FCC<P> {
        (props: P & { children: ReactElement }, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
}
```

You might want to use some inheritance to avoid maintaining other parts of the definition (displayName, propTypes, etc)

Comment: Please keep in mind, that thic code will affect whole codebase. It can confuse other developers on the project

Comment: Even more, it can be broken when React will change something in FunctionComponent. But author is aware of using more safe things like helper type, that's why I proposed such hucky solution

Comment: Ok, @Drag13 - in that case no problem )))) I was no attentive enough